# Making a Möbius transformation such that $f(3)=0$, $f(2)=1$, $f(1)=\infty$

Tags: mobius-transformation

We want to make a Möbius transformation such that $f(3)=0, \ f(2)=1, \ f(1)=\infty$, so we use the cross-ratio:

\begin{equation}
\frac{(w-w_1)(w_2-w_3)}{(w-w_3)(w_2-w_1}=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1}
\end{equation}

and insert for $w_1=0,\ w_2=1, \ w_3=\infty$ and $z_1=3, \  z_2=2, \ z_3=1$.

We get, where the infinity terms cancel out:

\begin{equation}
\frac{(w-0)(1-\infty)}{(w-\infty)(1-0)}=\frac{(z-3)(2-1)}{(z-1)(2-3)}\rightarrow w=\frac{(3-z)}{(z-1)}
\end{equation}

This looks like this:

[image]

Would this be OK?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the function $z \mapsto \dfrac{3-z}{z-1}$ satisfies all the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for this.

Comment: The graph you present corresponds to the *real valued* function $f(x)=\frac{3-x}{x-1}$. The graph of the complex map $z\mapsto \frac{3-z}{z-1}$ function cannot be envisioned is this manner as its graph is a subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: It was made with geogebra. Usually,it makes the right plot. Will you give it a  go on geogebra and see?

Comment: You seem to be responding to Mathew's comment without having understood it.

Comment: This is the way I usually plot at geobra. What he says still doesn't change the plot, as he has not given an alterantive on how to plot it.